# Dialog Fragment can't pass back events to calling Fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

In my Android App, I have navigation drawer activity as the `MainActivity`.
And I do not intend to do any tasks in the `MainActivity` other than navigation, I want to keep it simple and use `Fragments` for my tasks.

So I have a `Fragment` which calls a `DialogFragment`, the `DialogFragment` passes back events to the `Fragment`. My implementation is similar to the code given here in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#PassingEvents).

But, my app crashes when the dialog is needed to appear.

This is my `DialogFragment`:

```
class DialogSubjectsProgress: DialogFragment() {
    internal lateinit var listener: TheDialogListener

    interface TheDialogListener {
        fun onDialogCancel(dialog: DialogFragment)
        fun onDialogDismiss(dialog: DialogFragment)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        listener = context as TheDialogListener
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

        // show progress dialog
        val progressView = activity!!.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_progress_i, null)
        progressView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.progress_message).text = "Fetching data"

        return activity!!.let {
            val progressBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(it, R.style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dialog)
            progressBuilder
                .setView(progressView)
                .setOnCancelListener {
                    listener.onDialogCancel(this)
                }
                .setOnDismissListener {
                    listener.onDialogDismiss(this)
                }
                .create()
        }
    }
}
```

And this my `Fragment` code, which according to the docs is for an `Activity`:

```
class FragmentSubjects: Fragment(), DialogSubjectsProgress.TheDialogListener {

    // other code

    private fun addSubject() {
        // show progress dialog
        val progressDialog = DialogSubjectsProgress()
        progressDialog.show(activity!!.supportFragmentManager, "null")

        // todo
        // progressDialog.dismiss()

    }

    override fun onDialogCancel(dialog: DialogFragment) {
        // User canceled the dialog
    }

    override fun onDialogDismiss(dialog: DialogFragment) {
        // Dialog's work is done
        // todo
    }

}
```

I have found a solution to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14642166/8455110), but I don't really understand it because it is written in `Java`, and I don't understand `Java`. I need help in `Kotlin`!!

----edit----

This is the `log`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.kotlinappv3.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.example.kotlinappv3.DialogSubjectsProgress$TheDialogListener
        at com.example.kotlinappv3.DialogSubjectsProgress.onAttach(DialogSubjectsProgress.kt:27)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1404)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:874)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

The line

```
at com.example.kotlinappv3.DialogSubjectsProgress.onAttach(DialogSubjectsProgress.kt:27)
```

is pointing to

```
listener = context as TheDialogListener
```

in my `DialogFragment` code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your `addSubject` method instead of

```
activity!!.supportFragmentManager
```

use:

```
childFragmentManager
```

and in `DialogFragment` code, change:

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    listener = context as TheDialogListener
}
```

to:

```
override fun onAttachFragment(childFragment: Fragment?) {
    super.onAttachFragment(childFragment)
    listener = context as TheDialogListener
}
```

Comment: It still didn't work and showing the same error of `ClassCastException` as before.

Comment: @AkshdeepSingh then please attach the log to your question

Comment: I have included the log, you can see.

Comment: Well, even if I don't make a change in `addSubject` method, the dialog still works, what difference does it make actually?

Comment: @AkshdeepSingh I also should search about it a little.